# css first-letter transform для исправления несоответствия PTSans в Photoshop

Tags: css, шрифты, transform, first-letter

`PTSans` в `.psd` не соответствует его веб варианту, приходится исправлять текст путем `transform: scale`.

Проблема состоит в том, что заглавные буквы выходят ниже, чем в `Photoshop` - `.psd` макете. Хочу исправить это путем `transform: scale` для первых заглавных букв.

```css
p:first-letter {
  color: #abc;
  transform: scaleY(3);
 }
```

```html
<p>Слово АБВ</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть просто увеличить размер шрифта первой буквы?

```js
(function () { 
    var node = $(".first-p").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).first(),
        text = node.text().trim(),
        first = text.slice(0, 1);
    
    if (!node.length)
        return;
    
    node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
    node.before('<span class="f-latter">' + first + '</span>');
})();
```

```css
.f-latter {
color: red;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 40px;
transform: scaleY(4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="first-p">Слово АБВ</p>
<p>Слово АБВ</p>
```

Comment: Тогда он и шире станет, а нужно только выше.

Comment: transform: scale не применим к псевдокласу first-latter. Это возможно не самый простой вариант, но рабочий.

Comment: Спасибо! но я должен использовать только css. Видимо, никак нельзя исправить несоответствие шрифта в фотошопе и браузерах...